# How to get revision history of a file using OneDrive for business API

Tags: onedrive

I am integrating OneDrive for business (REST API) with our Platform. I can upload a file and update the files contents using the upload API. But how do I get the revision history of a file. The API which I am using is listed below.

[Upload a file](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use OneDrive for business API to get file revisions (versions), but you can use SharePoint API to get them.

Use this link to get file versions:

- GET
  "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@v)/Versions?@v='/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx'"

where:

"email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com" - is email of your drive

"tenant-my.sharepoint.com" - EndPoint of your drive

Response of this link looks like this JSON:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.FileVersions",
  "value": [
    {
      "odata.type": "SP.FileVersion",
      "odata.id": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/SP.FileVersionf1111111-aaaa-1234-5678-90abcdef1234",
      "odata.editLink": "SP.FileVersionf1111111-aaaa-1234-5678-90abcdef1234",
      "CheckInComment": "",
      "Created": "2013-04-27T15:57:57Z",
      "ID": 512,
      "IsCurrentVersion": false,
      "Length": "5716",
      "Size": 5716,
      "Url": "_vti_history/512/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx",
      "VersionLabel": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "odata.type": "SP.FileVersion",
      "odata.id": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/SP.FileVersion2ab46e3e-9614-43ff-ad03-252b1f4d0d90",
      "odata.editLink": "SP.FileVersion2ab46e3e-9614-43ff-ad03-252b1f4d0d90",
      "CheckInComment": "",
      "Created": "2013-04-27T15:58:39Z",
      "ID": 1024,
      "IsCurrentVersion": false,
      "Length": "7868",
      "Size": 7868,
      "Url": "_vti_history/1024/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx",
      "VersionLabel": "2.0"
    },
    {
      "odata.type": "SP.FileVersion",
      "odata.id": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/SP.FileVersion42f5f367-05ca-4131-84bf-79e7a6c0f77d",
      "odata.editLink": "SP.FileVersion42f5f367-05ca-4131-84bf-79e7a6c0f77d",
      "CheckInComment": "",
      "Created": "2013-04-27T15:58:43Z",
      "ID": 1536,
      "IsCurrentVersion": false,
      "Length": "7868",
      "Size": 7868,
      "Url": "_vti_history/1536/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx",
      "VersionLabel": "3.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

important parameters for you is:

"odata.editLink" after "SP.FileVersion" - it's unique Id of file version.
"ID" - it's version id of current file.

To download file version you can use this link:

- "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@v)/Versions(1024)/$value?@v='/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx'"

where "1024" - field "ID" from JSON.

To get info about last version of item you can use this link:

- GET
  "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@v)?@v='/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx'"

Response of this link looks like this JSON:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Files12/@Element",
  "odata.type": "SP.File",
  "odata.id": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx')",
  "odata.editLink": "Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx')",
  "CheckInComment": "",
  "CheckOutType": 2,
  "ContentTag": "{C4B73433-8AED-44C2-862A-746EBA4599EB},11,7",
  "CustomizedPageStatus": 0,
  "ETag": "\"{C4B73433-8AED-44C2-862A-746EBA4599EB},11\"",
  "Exists": true,
  "IrmEnabled": false,
  "Length": "7923",
  "Level": 1,
  "LinkingUri": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx?d=wc4b734338aed44c2862a746eba4599eb",
  "LinkingUrl": "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx?d=wc4b734338aed44c2862a746eba4599eb",
  "MajorVersion": 4,
  "MinorVersion": 0,
  "Name": "TEST_005.xlsx",
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx",
  "TimeCreated": "2013-04-27T15:57:55Z",
  "TimeLastModified": "2013-04-27T15:59:28Z",
  "Title": null,
  "UIVersion": 2048,
  "UIVersionLabel": "4.0",
  "UniqueId": "c4b73433-8aed-44c2-862a-746eba4599eb"
}
```

you can use this info, when you add a new revision of file.

"UniqueId" - it's right part of "odata.editLink" in versions JSON.
"UIVersion" - it's "ID" in version JSON.

To download last version of file - use this link:

- "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@v)/$value?@v='/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx'"

link:

- "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@v)/Versions(2048)/$value?@v='/personal/email_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TEST_005.xlsx'"

doesn't work. It will work if you add a new version of this file.

You can download last revision of item by using OneDrive API link:

- "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/driveId/items/driveItemId/content"

but this link doesn't work if you use Service Account authentication

Answer (score 0):

Till date there is no api resource for getting version or revision history of a file. Follow the [link](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm) to know about available operations on items in one drive for business.